# External CSS properties not getting applied

Tags: css

I am primarily a mainframe developer and maintain a front end web application which was built in 2002 (but I joined it since 2012) and compatible only with IE 5. We have been surviving all these years with compatibility mode in IE. Now our client want us to make it compatible with IE 11. We just started off with a basic proof of concept taking one page and we noticed a couple of things with javascripts (fixed).

But we are stuck with an issue with our external style sheets. CSS properties are not being applied. When checked in debugger, there are check boxes are available for Position & Visibility attributes but top, left, and other things don't have check boxes and doesn't seem to apply. I researched a lot before posting this question but couldn't find a right answer. Here is a sample div and CSS.

```
<DIV id=PD_DIV_SEARCHBY class=srchSearchBy style="VISIBILITY: visible">
   ....
   ....
</DIV>

.srchSearchBy
{ position:absolute; visibility:hidden; -> Seems to work
  top:75; left:5; width:225; height:135; } -> Don't work
```

Please pardon my knowledge if something was mentioned inappropriately.

Thanks

Comment: For some reason the DIV was not printed in my question. Here it is.  <DIV id=PD_DIV_SEARCHBY class=srchSearchBy style="VISIBILITY: visible">


</DIV>

Comment: How is it referenced in the html

Comment: Try adding units in the CSS.  Like `top:75px` and `width: 225px` etc.

Comment: Yup Cassidy is right, you need units.

Comment: Well to begin with, you need to wrap your `id` and `class` names in double quotes ""

Comment: Try adding `units` eg: `px` and `quotes` to your `html`

Comment: Hi All, adding quotes worked. Sorry for missing such a basic thing but I was carried away by the fact that it was working in IE 5. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, you should add quotes to your id and class declarations. 
You also need units for your dimensions.

If your styles are still not being applied, it may be because another rule is taking precedence in [Cascade Order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) or [Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). You may be able to use a more specific CSS selector. If not, you can use the `!important` exception, however this should be used sparingly.

**HTML**

```
<DIV id="PD_DIV_SEARCHBY" class="srchSearchBy">
   ....
   ....
</DIV>
```

**CSS**

```
.srchSearchBy{ 
    position:absolute; 
    visibility:hidden;
    top:75px !important; 
    left:5px !important; 
    width:225px !important; 
    height:135px !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. That worked. Sorry for the missing the basics, but I am learing :)